# Saving the state of radio button

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Is there any way to save radio button state or is it even possible? As in the radio button will stay checked irrespective of the session going on unless the user doesn't change it on click.

I'm using Bootstrap-switch for radio button. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by saving the state? are you using php to print that radio button?

Comment: Save the state in the database?

Comment: @Fadey No. It is just to show. It is a flag of sorts. The user will be able to raise a flag and remove it according to his/her wish.

Comment: @davey Yes. I have thought about it. But it will tend to get complicated as number of radio buttons is uncertain. Any other options?

Comment: Save it in a cookie then?

Comment: you must provide more info on your intentions, if no php is printing your radio buttons, then you could use javascript to keep those on.

Comment: @davey That won't help me when cookies are cleared.

Comment: @Fadey It works like this --- The user will log in and raise a flag, if a task is pending. He will remove it when it gets completed. Now the task can get days to be completed, till then I need to save the state of that flag (for me here, that flag is my radio button)

Comment: then you must use some kind of a database to keep that data. you could use Mysql to keep your data, and using ajax methods to make it look seamless application, Or keeping your data on json file using Angularjs to build your app.

Comment: @Fadey Actually the problem with using DB is, the number of tasks is uncertain hence the flags raised will be uncertain. Also the tasks aren't predefined so I'm not sure wat structure of table should I use.

Comment: you could always use a non-rational DB like mongoDB which could behave just like a class data, this might have the flexibility that you need. But I'm pretty sure you could come-up with a proper table design for your app, you just need to define it very well.

Comment: @Fadey Thank you for your inputs! I'll work along those lines. :)